# How to make safari suggest me subdomains if enter a main domain?

Tags: safari, google-chrome

For example I want to visit b2b.vtt.ru (it is in my history). But I don't remember the subdomain. If I enter "Vtt" safari doesn't suggest me anything. It is annoying. I always used to type domains instead of subdomains when I used chrome and safari
I appreciate your help

[image: safari]
[image: opera]